# why autocomplition is not working for application.properties file in vs code for spring boot project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, application.properties

I have created a Spring Boot project in Visual Studio Code. My issue is that autocompletion is not working in my `application.settings` file, it works fine in other parts of project. Any help will be appreciated.

[Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDOa4.png)

Comment: What kind of smart tips are you thinking of? Does it exist in other IDEs?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the necessary plugins/extension installed in your VS Code.

Try installing [Spring Boot Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Pivotal.vscode-spring-boot) and try again.

Comment: yeah I have already installed all the required extension/plugin for spring boot .autocompletion is working fine in other parts of the project but not inside the application.properties file

Answer (score 0):

**vs code => settings =>** Editor: Quick Suggestions

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": "on",
        "comments": "on",
        "strings": "on"
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem but autocompletion was working when I installed the "Spring Boot Extension Pack" extension.
Let me know if it works for you.